# How can we maintain State in Webservices?

Tags: web-services

How can we maintain State in Webservices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web services are by nature stateless. Any attempt to maintain state is a hack, since you may hold something that will be used by the next request from the user, which will never come.

If you really need it, just keep it in session. For larger data sets, keep them out of session, but add session listener to cleanup that data when session expires.

Comment: -1 about the hack statement.  Storing session information in SOAP headers is a valid non-hack solution.  Many companies have their own proprietary SOAP header for this very purpose.  Basically if what you say is true, then ASP.NET's session state is a hack because HTTP is stateless.

Answer (score 0):

Services should be stateless; if there's state to be maintained, it's the client's job to do it.

Comment: Me and the guy whose answer was accepted.  Oh, and Werner Vogel, the CTO of Amazon.  http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1142065.  And the fact that HTTP is a request/response protocol - you have to take extraordinary measures to preserve state, like cookies or URL rewriting or writing to a database.

Comment: Extraordinary measures..?  Database/data store, cookies, query string, SOAP Headers are not extraordinary.  Take a look: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-accesstoken.html  Yahoo API maintains state.

Comment: At least you're consistent.  Down vote all of us; I'm fine with that.